# xymon-4.3.28/configure.server: 94: .: Can't open build/fping.sh

Tags: networking, network-manager, network-monitoring

I downloaded and installed all the prerequisites, and I run a configure file to build `xymon`.
But I am getting the following error:

```
xymon-4.3.28/configure.server: 94: .: Can't open build/fping.sh
```

Please help...
I am using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Comment: How exactly did you download / unpack the xymon-4.3.28 source code? did you use `sudo` (which may have made the `build/` directory unwritable to non-privileged users)?

Answer (score 0):

Really you do not need to compile this application by yourself.

It is packaged as [`xymon`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=xymon) in official Ubuntu repositories (*universe* pocket):

> [image: xymon package]
>   (Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS has 4.3.28-3build1)

You should enable *universe* pocket

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

and then install the application:

```
sudo apt-get install xymon
```

---

If you are trying to compile it just for fun - then enable source code repositories in Software & Update, then get all necessary build dependencies

```
sudo apt-get build-dep xymon
apt-get source xymon
```

and so on.